# Date Format with Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a textbox and using `data-ng-model="EmpDetails[0].DateOfJoining"` So what happens here is the date comes along with the time and I only want the date. 
I have seen multiple place where you use `{{EmpDetails[0].DateOfJoining | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}}` but what I want is within the model, its got a 2 way bind.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use moment.js for formatting it. Make filter and return date format as expected.

Comment: What about `input type="date"`? ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bdate%5D)). Otherwise, make a directive that collaborates with `ngModelController` and add a `$parser` and a `$formatter` to do whatever transformation you want.

Comment: Would someone have already done the code, I would imagine this being a common requirement.